# Paginator prev not working with Ajax View

Tags: cakephp, paginator

I'm having this issue where the previous button of the paginator is disabled (have disabled class) by default, even if I am in to second or third or any page. If I remove the 'id => prevPage' and 'id => nextPage' then it works fine but I have to use it to make another ajax request.

I'm using this in my ajax view..

```
echo $this->Paginator->prev('< ' . __('Zur'), array('id' => 'prevPage'), null, array('class' => 'prev disabled'));
echo $this->Paginator->next(__('Vor') . ' >', array('id' => 'nextPage'), null, array('class' => 'next disabled'));
```

while in my controller, I have;

```
if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
$this->autoRender = false;
$this->set('products',$this->paginate('Product'));
$this->set('page',$page);
$this->render('ajaxView');
}
```

I did a little googling which suggested me it might be bug.. is it? How do I solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find the error, but I fixed the error by going through other way. I was using 'offset' while I was paginating in the controller before which had introduced the error, but using the other way around by requesting to '.../page:3?q=' on the ajax call, did solved the problem. Thanks to @hereshem for the quick fix.